# How to stop EditText from moving up when keyboard appears

Tags: android, xml, layout, android-edittext, keyboard

In a Bottom Navigation Activity I've a Fragment with a button, an EditText and a TextView.

The problem is that when I focus the EditText to write with the keyboard it moves up and the button bugs in it. How can I solve?

[image: keyboard off]
[image: keyboard on]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"

    <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="178dp"
            android:gravity="start|top"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/output"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            android:autofillHints="" app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.386"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button" app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.666"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.TextView" android:scrollbars="vertical" android:textSize="18sp"
    />
    <EditText
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="178dp"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
            android:gravity="start|top"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/input"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.666"
            android:autofillHints="" android:hint="@string/hint" android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button" app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.574"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"/>
    <Button
            android:text="@string/button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/button"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498" app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use this
' android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" '
in  AndroidMenifest.xml file

```
 <activity
       android:name=".ui.activity.approve_pending.ApprovalsActivity"
       android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" />
```

You will find more information here  https://developer.android.com/training/keyboard-input/visibility

Comment: Your solution solved my problem, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Your constraints are probably what's causing this behavior.

Try removing the bottom constraint on your EditText, and setting the top constraint on your button to the bottom of the EditText instead of the top of the parent. I believe that will fix it.

Answer (score 0):

it work for me ,it grateful ,try it

android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"