# How to set view to above of the keyboard?

Tags: android

I want to set my linear layout which contain in Relative layout exactly above the keyboard.
for this I set Linear Layout to `alignParentBottom="true`" and programmatically set bottom margin is equal to keyboard height, but its not working

```
multipleMediaRelLyaout.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onGlobalLayout() {

                        Rect r = new Rect();
                        multipleMediaRelLyaout.getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(r);
                        int screenHeight = multipleMediaRelLyaout.getRootView().getHeight();
                        keyboardH = screenHeight - r.bottom;

                        final RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)edittextLinLayout.getLayoutParams();
                        params.bottomMargin=keyboardH ;//not working
                        //params.bottomMargin=800; its working
                        edittextLinLayout.setLayoutParams(params);
                    }
                });
```

Comment: Can you post your xml layout?

Comment: its simple...<RelativeLayout><extra thing and views><LinearLayout...alignparent bottom>----</LinearLayout></RelativeLayout>

Answer (score 0):

Use this 'android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" ' in your menifest file. Try the bellow solution
https://stackoverflow.com/a/63816981/3916792

Comment: dont want adjustpan, it scattere other views contain in main RelativeLayout